# Is accessing Bitmap.Width in a loop slower than accessing a pre-assigned variable because of reference type overhead?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I code on C# Windows Forms.

When i call references, it reduces speed, i mean it is much slower in compare to value types, it is because of:

1. It calls .Net Framework every time. Because it is managed code?
2. Because it is a reference type and it is the same problem in other languages with unmanaged code too. Yes?

Is it because of it is managed code at all?

The next code shows:

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Method();
    }

    private void Method()
    {
        Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(100, 100);
        int width = 0;
        int w = bitmap1.Width;

        for (int i = 0; i < 500000000; i++)
        {
            //width = bitmap1.Width; // slower
            //width = w; // faster
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: I mean reference types are slower than value types when we call them and work with them, it is just fact, i ask why? Because it is managed code, i just don't know.

Comment: Reference types are not slower than value types, except for GC overhead.

Comment: They are slower, when i use them in for loop, it takes longer than with value types. I read that is it because it calls .net framework every time, not becasue of that? Is it a problem in other languages too?

Comment: Can you prove that with small code example and results?

Comment: I think you're confused about what [managed code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb318664%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) actually is. You are trying to relate two completely different concepts together.

Comment: Of course i can prove, i just thought you know, wait.

Comment: I wrote a code, so, it is absolutely not because of the fact that it is managed code? And it is the same thing as in other languages with unmanaged code. Right?

Comment: Incorrectly done benchmarking is often the explanation of odd speed claims.

Comment: To avoid getting bogged down in whether the assumptions the OP is making are appropriate, I've edited the title to focus on the interesting part of the question: *why* is Bitmap.Width slower than a simple value-type access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's slower because `.Width` actually calls internally GDI method, which does other calculations, and it also allocates memory briefly.

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Image.cs,9284bc31cef9a24b,references

See `Width` property.

It has nothing to do with value types vs reference types.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the example given, as @Chris Eelmaa has effectively shown, is *side effects*: it isn't actually testing the hypothesis that accessing values through reference types imposes substantial overhead. A simple experiment for this hypothesis would be to define a reference type that wraps a value type:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var valueType = 100;
        var referenceType = new IntWrapper(100);

        var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        int assignee;

        for (int i = 0; i < 500000000; i++)
        {
            assignee = valueType;
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Accessed valueType 500m times in {0}ms", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        stopWatch.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < 500000000; i++)
        {
            assignee = referenceType.IntAccessor;
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Accessed referenceType 500m times in {0}ms", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class IntWrapper
{
    private readonly int _intField;

    public IntWrapper(int i)
    {
        _intField = i;
    }

    public int IntAccessor
    {
        get { return _intField; }
    }
}
```

When I run this console application, I see results like these:

[image: reftype vs valuetype]

So there *does* appear to be a performance penalty to accessing the reference type's property. That overhead doesn't have to do with managed vs. unmanaged code, however - the use of the latter in a .NET program requires special annotations, *all* the code in the above example is "managed" as the Framework defines it. The actual difference likely comes down to compiler optimizations, as @hatchet described. We could find out for sure by examining the IL emitted by the compiler for each of the loops. For now, I'll have to leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: That difference is insane. Make sure that you have +optimize enabled and you're running release mode, there should be zero difference (it is for me).

Comment: Indeed, I was running in Debug mode. Switched to Release, the referenceType loop is still 1 second slower. Haven't played about with optimizations yet.